# C# dice game logic errors

Tags: c#, arrays

I'm learning C# are I am writing a program that makes an array fills it with 50 random numbers1-6 like dice and then checks how many times each value or 'side' comes up.  I made a dice game in python earlier in the week and I had a lot of trouble so I made i= j= and match= print outs to test if the loops and matching were iterating correctly, so I did the same here and I noticed a few logic errors:

1. the i loop seems to iterate fine but for every 1 iteration of i, j should iterate 50 times but i only get it once.
2. The i OR j loops don't iterate at all unless in line 47 it states while j > dice.Length.  Writing as it should be j < dice.Length makes it not iterate at all.  The 50 random numbers display on screen so i know dice is 50 in length and j is 0.
3. Thirdly in line 50 if dice[i] == dice[j] I get an error that j isn't valid unless I declare j above the for loop, and if I do that I can't do int j = 0 in the for loop, so I scrapped the for loop and did a while loop, but it still only adds a value for the first match and not the next possible 49.

I am only coding inside the static void since it's a simple console application, thank you for your help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace wk8hw2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {//staticvoid
            int size = 50;
            int diceSides = 7;
            int matchAdd = 0;
            int[] dice = new int[size];
            int[] match = new int[diceSides];
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int j = 0;

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to roll the dice " + size + " times.");
            Console.ReadKey();

            for (int i = 0; i < dice.Length; i++)//roll dice
            {
                dice[i] = rnd.Next(1, diceSides);
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < dice.Length; i++)//show dice
            {
                Console.Write(dice[i] + " ");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("done showing dice");//DEBUG
            for (int i = 0; i < dice.Length; i++)//outer match loop
            {
                Console.Write("i = " + i);//DEBUG
                if (match[dice[i]] == 0)//if not matched add to match array
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("not yet matched");
                    matchAdd = 1;
                }
                else//if alerady matched add no more
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("already matched");
                    matchAdd = 0;
                }
                j = 0;
                while (j > dice.Length)//inner match loopSUPPOSED TRO BE LESS THAN
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("j = " + j);
                    if (dice[i] == dice[j])//if equal add to match array
                    {
                        match[dice[i]] = match[dice[i]] + matchAdd;
                        Console.WriteLine("val " + match[dice[i]]);
                    }
                    j++;
                }
            }//endFORouter

            for (int i = 1; i < match.Length; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i + " came up " + match[i] + " times.");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }//endstaticvoid
    }
}
```

Comment: If you're logically rolling 6-sided dice, don't have a variable `diceSides` with a value or `7`. Make it `6` since that makes sense and change the rolling statement to `rnd.Next(diceSides) + 1`.

Comment: having the end value be 6 isn't the issue, in c# apparently the max value you input is actually max+1, if i put 6 i only get ever get 1-5, if i input 7 as max i get 1-6

Comment: But if you do `rnd.Next(6) + 1` like I suggested,  you get (0-5) + 1 which gives you 1 - 6, in a much clearer way without needing to confuse the reader thinking you're trying to roll 7-sided dice.

Comment: @itsme86 I see what you are getting St now, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the first answer however...you said you are learning C# and based on the namespace this is a homework assignment and you are most likely learning about arrays so I would rewrite it a bit different

You seem to be doing way to many loops and generally doing to much. Make your code as simple as possible and name your variables to tell anyone reading the code what they do.

```
int numberOfRolls = 50;
int diceSides = 6;
int[] dice = new int[numberOfRolls];
int[] match = new int[diceSides];
Random random = new Random();

Console.WriteLine("Press any key to roll the dice " + numberOfRolls + " times.");
Console.ReadKey();

for (int rollCount = 0; rollCount < numberOfRolls; rollCount++)
{
    var rollResult = random.Next(1, diceSides+1);
    match[rollResult-1]++;
}

for (int i = 0; i < match.Length; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i+1 + " came up " + match[i] + " times.");
}

Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: thank you so much for this, I had a hard time gathering what you were doing at first but i'm pretty sure I'm understanding it now:  You roll the dice and store it in rollResult, and then you add 1 to the match array in spot roll result( I assume the +1 is accounting for the fact that 0 is the first spot in the array and 1 is the minimum value we're working with?)  If i wanted to print each roll as it happened would i print rollResult on the line under where it is set?

Comment: I should jave added a bit more documentation, but yes you are correct about the -1 in match[rollResult-1] as well as the diceSides+1. You are also correct about printing the rollResult by adding a line in the first loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'd rewrite this whole thing as:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
const int diceSides = 6;
const int numDice = 50;

Console.WriteLine("Press any key to roll the dice {0} times.", numDice);
Console.ReadKey();

var diceByValue = Enumerable.Range(0, numDice)
                      .Select(_ => rnd.Next(diceSides) + 1)
                      .GroupBy(v => v)
                      .OrderBy(g => g.Key);

foreach (var group in diceByValue)
    Console.WriteLine("{0} came up {1} times.", group.Key, group.Count());
```

Comment: Just forgot to use numDice in Range ;)

Comment: I'm new to programming i'm in my first class so I'm trying to do it with simple logic instead of using the more powerful statements of each language.  I simply don't know what enumerable.range is or .select .groupby, but I am certainly going to look into exactly what all those commands do so thank you